# Variable Scope issue in C#

Tags: c#, variables, scope

Here is the deal. I have a Master-Detail Grid scenario. The Master GridView is loaded when the page is loaded. I am using a DataView of same DataTable which loads the Master to load the Detail GridView, by filtering what I need to show in the DetailGridView. Everything works fine when I view the first row of the MasterGridView. When I try to view the second row, I the the error "column[number] not found. I also notice that the "table" variable is nothing.

```
public partial class Gridview_Template : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataReader reader = DBSqlHelperFactory.ExecuteReader(
            myconnection,
            "crm_getcustomersummary",
            new SqlParameter("@customerid", "99999")
        );
        table.Load(reader);
        MasterGridView.DataSource = table;
        MasterGridView.DataBind();
    }

    protected void detailGrid_DataSelect(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchValue ="number="  + values.ToString();

        DataView dv = new DataView(
            table, searchValue, "number", DataViewRowState.OriginalRows
        );
        DetailGridView.DataSource = dv;

        // ...
    }
}
```

Am I to put the "table" variable in a session state so it exists across call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to persist the table between postback, then you may want to take a look at ViewState. Session is used more for persisting information across different pages.